# single backslash needed in SQL Server query from Python / SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, csv, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a query using the `BULK INSERT` function in SQL Server 2014 via a python script to insert a large CSV file into a table in a database. I have the following example code:

```
import pymssql
import sqlalchemy

engine = create_engine('connection_string_goes_here', encoding="utf-8")
table_name = 'my_table'
source_path = 'C:\path\to\csv\test.csv'
q = ("BULK INSERT " + table_name + " " +
     "FROM '" + source_path + "' " +
     "WITH ( DATAFILETYPE = 'char', " +
     "FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', " +
     "ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n')")
connection = engine.connect()
connection.execute(q)
connection.close()
```

The error I get is:

`(pymssql.OperationalError) (4861, Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\\path\\to\\csv\\test.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).DB-Lib error message 20018…`

I believe this is because of a double backslash issue. The backslashes are being literally included in the BULK INSERT statement instead of being translated into single backslashes. I don't see anything in the SQL Server error log.

My setup uses MS SQL Server Express 2014 and Python 2.7.9 running on a separate Windows box.

I have tried using raw strings (`r'C:\path\to\csv\test.csv`) and the `decode` string function on the `source_path`, but neither have helped.

Comment: The path in your query is a path *on the server*? (it must be)

Comment: Yes. It is the path on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like using `/` instead of `\` works.